# How can I remove an element from a list, with lodash?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have an object that looks like this:

```
var obj = {
    "objectiveDetailId": 285,
    "objectiveId": 29,
    "number": 1,
    "text": "x",
    "subTopics": [{
        "subTopicId": 1,
        "number": 1
    }, {
        "subTopicId": 2,
        "number": 32
    }, {
        "subTopicId": 3,
        "number": 22
    }]
}
var stToDelete = 2;
```

I have `lodash` installed in my application for other things. Is there an efficient way to use `lodash` to delete the entry: `{"subTopicId":2, "number":32}` from the `obj` object?

Or is there a javascript way to do this?

Comment: you can just use `splice` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove item from a list

Comment: Changed the title because removing 4 from an array [1,4,5] cannot be done this way.  Yes, I do understand that arrays can be implemented from the hash/object and probably are, but there is a subtle difference in these two.  To remove from an array you would use `result = _.pull(arr, value)`  This would remove all the matching values from the list.

Answer (score 307, accepted):

As lyyons pointed out in the comments, more idiomatic and lodashy way to do this would be to use [`_.remove`](http://lodash.com/docs#remove), like this

```
_.remove(obj.subTopics, {
    subTopicId: stToDelete
});
```

Apart from that, you can pass a predicate function whose result will be used to determine if the current element has to be removed or not.

```
_.remove(obj.subTopics, function(currentObject) {
    return currentObject.subTopicId === stToDelete;
});
```

---

Alternatively, you can create a new array by filtering the old one with [`_.filter`](https://lodash.com/docs#filter) and assign it to the same object, like this

```
obj.subTopics = _.filter(obj.subTopics, function(currentObject) {
    return currentObject.subTopicId !== stToDelete;
});
```

Or

```
obj.subTopics = _.filter(obj.subTopics, {subTopicId: stToKeep});
```

Comment: The reason that this answer rocks is because you can use a *predicate function*, which is exactly what I was looking for.  Removing an element is trivial if you know the index, but what about when you *don't* know the index?

Comment: Might be worth mentioning [_.filter](https://lodash.com/docs#filter) if you don't want to mutate the original array....

Comment: @cale_b Thank you :-) Updated the answer with the `_.filter` version.

Comment: @thefourtheye `_.filter ` return an element if the predicate is true. Your implementation will return all unwanted elements instead of those you want to keep

Comment: @thefourtheye you should use `_.reject` instead of `_.filter` to use the same predicate. Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44553188/1330674) for more details!

Comment: Awesome the idea of predicate works great in my current scenario

Answer (score 29):

Just use vanilla JS. You can use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove the element:

```
obj.subTopics.splice(1, 1);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JcF7U/3/)

Comment: the user asks `Is there an efficient way to use _lodash to delete`

Comment: @Andy You are right, but what if the index is not known already?

Comment: splice() is the best approach if you want your array to be mutated. If you use remove then it returns the new array and this has to be reassigned.

Comment: If you wish to remove an item from an array by its index in the array (obviously, you have this index if you want to perform the remove action in this way), then using the splice method is the most efficient (and easy) way to do it. No need for comparing anything and making the code more complicated and vulnerable for bugs and errors...

Answer (score 28):

you can do it with `_pull`.

```
_.pull(obj["subTopics"] , {"subTopicId":2, "number":32});
```

check the [reference](https://lodash.com/docs#pull)

Comment: Per the docs, [`_.pull`](https://lodash.com/docs#pull) uses *strict equality for comparisons, i.e. ===*. Two different plain objects will never compare as equal by `===` (or by `==` for that matter). Thus your code above will never remove any elements from the array.

Comment: Yet, that's the only one that works with strings in array. `_.remove` just flushes the array.

Comment: I still think this is the right answer. JS .filter removes all elements matching, JS .splice requires that I know the index, _.remove iterates over all elements of the array thus being less efficient. _.pull is exactly what I want: _.pull(array, itemToRemove).

Answer (score 28):

You can now use [_.reject](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#reject) which allows you to filter based on what you need to get rid of, instead of what you need to keep.

unlike `_.pull` or `_.remove` that only work on arrays, `._reject` is working on any  `Collection`

```
obj.subTopics = _.reject(obj.subTopics, (o) => {
  return o.number >= 32;
});
```

Comment: In addition to this answer, the original array  is never mutated, and easier to read when setting up conditional logic on your return statements.

Answer (score 18):

The easiest and most convenient way -

```js
_.without([2, 1, 2, 3], 1, 2);
// => [3]
```

[`_.without`](https://lodash.com/docs#without) documentation.

Answer (score 9):

There are four ways to do this as I know

```
const array = [{id:1,name:'Jim'},{id:2,name:'Parker'}];
const toDelete = 1;
```

The first:

```
_.reject(array, {id:toDelete})
```

The second one is :

```
_.remove(array, {id:toDelete})
```

In this way the array will be mutated.

The third one is :

```
_.differenceBy(array,[{id:toDelete}],'id')
// If you can get remove item 
// _.differenceWith(array,[removeItem])
```

The last one is:

```
_.filter(array,({id})=>id!==toDelete)
```

I am learning `lodash`

Answer to make a record, so that I can find it later.

Comment: I was looking for `reject`

Answer (score 2):

In Addition to @thefourtheye answer, using **predicate**  instead of traditional anonymous functions:

```
  _.remove(obj.subTopics, (currentObject) => {
        return currentObject.subTopicId === stToDelete;
    });
```

OR

```
obj.subTopics = _.filter(obj.subTopics, (currentObject) => {
    return currentObject.subTopicId !== stToDelete;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

lodash and typescript

```
const clearSubTopics = _.filter(obj.subTopics, topic => (!_.isEqual(topic.subTopicId, 2)));
console.log(clearSubTopics);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple lodash function with array and deleting it with the index number.

```
index_tobe_delete = 1

fruit = [{a: "apple"}, {b: "banana"}, {c: "choco"}]
_.filter(fruit, (value, key)=> {
return (key !== index_tobe_delete)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **removeItemFromArrayByPath** function which includes some lodash functions and splice

```js
/**
 * Remove item from array by given path and index
 *
 * Note: this function mutates array.
 *
 * @param {Object|Array} data (object or array)
 * @param {Array|String} The array path to remove given index
 * @param {Number} index to be removed from given data by path
 *
 * @returns {undefined}
 */

const removeItemFromArrayByPath = (data, arrayPath, indexToRemove) => {
  const array = _.get(data, arrayPath, []);
  if (!_.isEmpty(array)) {
    array.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
  }
};
```

You can check the examples here:
https://codepen.io/fatihturgut/pen/NWbxLNv