# How eliminate some elements from a JSON model in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I am developing an applicaiton where I am getting the following JSON data from the server:

```
var requests =     
    {
    "id":"12","start":"2016-05-20 07:00:00",
    "end":"2016-05-20
    10:00:00",
    "price":"0",
    "paid":"no",
    "accepted":"yes",
    "reviewed_by_provider":"no",
    "reviewed_by_client":"no",
    "created_by_user_id":"35",
    "provided_to_user_id":"36"
    },
    {"id":"13",
    "start":"2016-05-20 07:30:00",
    "end":"2016-05-20 11:00:00",
    "price":"0",
    "paid":"no",
    "accepted":"yes",
    "reviewed_by_provider":"no",
    "reviewed_by_client":"no",
    "created_by_user_id":"35",
    "provided_to_user_id":"36"
    },
    {
    "id":"14",
    "start":"2016-05-20 07:30:00",
    "end":"2016-05-20 10:00:00",
    "price":"0",
    "paid":"no",
    "accepted":"no",
    "reviewed_by_provider":"no",
    "reviewed_by_client":"no",
    "created_by_user_id":"35",
    "provided_to_user_id":"36"
    }
```

In JavaScript by running a for each loop, I want to eliminate the sets where `"accepted":"no"` and then from the remaining sets, I want to delete all the other parameters except `id`, `end` and `start`.

How do I do this in JavaScript? 
Note that I am developing this application in angularJS.

Any ideas?

Comment: That's not JSON. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: If you are willing to use a external lib for this, lodash is really nice for exactly what you are trying to do. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21281286/how-can-i-remove-an-element-from-a-list-with-lodash

Comment: Oh sorry, I miss wrote. Its without the [] signs

Comment: Since I can't actually provide an answer (post was marked duplicate) I'll just say it here. This is how you'd what ur asking in lodash: First: _.remove(requests, {
    accepted: 'no'
}); Then I'd follow to what the link suggested as duplicated.

Comment: @wdanda thank you for this information. I have managed to filter the request for accepted == no but how do I remove other parameters such as paid, price,etc?

Comment: Use lodash omit. See more here: https://lodash.com/docs#omit Just keep in mind this one actually returns new object that you need to reassign.