# Remove an entry from a collection when an attribute matches a particular value using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a collection,

```
 var users = [
       {'user': 'Mike', 'age': 11,  'description': 'Null'},
       {'user': 'Kiddo', 'age': 36,  'description': 'Not Available'},
       { 'user': 'Jack', 'age': 36,  'description': 'test'}
     ];
```

How can use lodash library to remove the entries which has 'description' :'Not Available' ?

Edit 1 :
Tried using the below ,

```
function removeItemsByAttrValue (collection, attrValue, matchValue) { 
    return _.filter(collection, val => val.attrValue !== matchValue);
}
```

Invoked it like,

```
 removeItemsByAttrValue (users, 'description', 'Not Available');
```

Somehow, this didn't filter the item.

Comment: Filter, reject or remove.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove an element from a list, with lodash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21281286/how-can-i-remove-an-element-from-a-list-with-lodash)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built in JS method for arrays `filter`

```
var filteredUsers = users.filter(val => val.description !== 'Not Available');
```

Lodash also has a filter method, but it's unnecessary to use here

```
_.filter(users, val => val.description !== 'Not Available')
```

Comment: Thanks, when I used it inside a function and passed the params, somehow it doesn't filter. I edited the question with what I tried. But if the filter is used as it is it works.

Comment: You would need to update your function to look like this: `_.filter(collection, val => val[attrValue] !== matchValue);` notice the bracket notation @Vishnu

Comment: Thanks again, I will try it out!