# how to delete the element in json Array

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

This is the code i need to delete the second element in completely using nodejs

```
[
{
    "sno": 1,
    "brandName": "EPIDOSIN 8 MG INJECTION",
    "price": "Rs. 17",
    "packagingOfProduct": "1 vial(s) (1 ML injection each)",
    },
{
    "sno": 2,
    "brandName": "ALTACEF 1.5 GM INJECTION",
    "price": "Rs. 327",
    "packagingOfProduct": "1 vial(s) (1 injection each)",

}]
```

Comment: Related answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396088/how-do-i-remove-an-object-from-an-array-with-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396088/how-do-i-remove-an-object-from-an-array-with-javascript)

Comment: Need more information. based on what do you want to remove the element?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `splice` function of `Array`

```
var data = [
{
    "sno": 1,
    "brandName": "EPIDOSIN 8 MG INJECTION",
    "price": "Rs. 17",
    "packagingOfProduct": "1 vial(s) (1 ML injection each)",
    },
{
    "sno": 2,
    "brandName": "ALTACEF 1.5 GM INJECTION",
    "price": "Rs. 327",
    "packagingOfProduct": "1 vial(s) (1 injection each)",

}]
```

`data.splice(1, 1);`

where first argument is index and second argument is number of element need to remove

**Ref:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

**Update:** If you want to delete particular attribute of object, here is example to delete brandName from each object inside array

`data.forEach( obj => delete obj.brandName);`

Comment: If it really is JSON, then you'd need to parse it into a java object first, then do your manipulations, and then (if you want), dump it back out to a JSON string.

Comment: You are right for Java but question asked for NodeJS and we do not need to convert in NodeJS until json data in string.

Comment: if there are plenty of data if want to delete particular element how to do ??

Comment: You have array of object. Are you trying to delete particular attribute of object ?

Answer (score 0):

```
let tab = [ {
    "sno": 1,
    "brandName": "EPIDOSIN 8 MG INJECTION",
    "price": "Rs. 17",
    "packagingOfProduct": "1 vial(s) (1 ML injection each)",
    }, {
    "sno": 2,
    "brandName": "ALTACEF 1.5 GM INJECTION",
    "price": "Rs. 327",
    "packagingOfProduct": "1 vial(s) (1 injection each)",

}]
```

to remove the second element try using :

```
tab.pop(tab[1])
```

or

```
delete(tab[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash.js for nodejs.

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var data = [
{
        "sno": 1,
            "brandName": "EPIDOSIN 8 MG INJECTION",
                "price": "Rs. 17",
                    "packagingOfProduct": "1 vial(s) (1 ML injection each)",
                        },
{
        "sno": 2,
            "brandName": "ALTACEF 1.5 GM INJECTION",
                "price": "Rs. 327",
                    "packagingOfProduct": "1 vial(s) (1 injection each)",

}];
_.remove(data, {
        sno: 2
});
console.log(data);
```

Please refer below link for more details

[How can I remove an element from a list, with lodash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21281286/how-can-i-remove-an-element-from-a-list-with-lodash)