# How to remove an element from an array in a nested object? (lodash)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, underscore.js, lodash

I had an object like

```
data: {
    registrationNumber: 'MH1234',
    type: 'xyz',
    driver: {
      user: {
        firstName: 'xyz',
        lastName: 'abc',
        email: 'xyz',
        phone: 1234,
        city: 'random',
        dateOfBirth: new Date(),
        groups: [1]
      }
    },
    owner: {
      user: {
        firstName: 'xyz',
        lastName: 'abc',
        email: 'xyz',
        phone: '1234',
        city: 'random',
        groups: [1, 2]
      },
      kyc: [
        {
          method: 'xyz',
          id: 'abcd'
        },
        {
          method: 'xyz',
          id: 'abcd'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

how can i remove the element at path `data.owner.kyc.0` ?

I have tried using _.unset() but it is not ideal since the array still shows 2 elements after deletion

Comment: you could do `obj.data.owner.kyc = obj.data.owner.kyc.splice(1);`, no lodash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `lodash` to accomplish this.

With `.shift()` to remove first element from array.

```
let newData = {...data}

newData.owner.kyc.shift()
```

With `.splice()` to remove elements from a certain point.

```
let newData = {...data}

newData.owner.kyc.splice(0, 1)
```

With `.filter()` to remove items that don't match a specified condition

```
let newData = {...data}

newData.owner.kyc = newData.owner.kyc.filter((item, index) => {
   return index !== 0
})
```

Since you're using React, you would want to have this data in component-state so that when you actually remove something from the array, the App updates to reflect the new results.

See sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-fog-2yhwd

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: data
  };

  removeFirstItem = () => {
    const { data } = this.state;

    let newData = { ...data };

    newData.owner.kyc.shift();

    this.setState({
      data: newData
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>Car Info:</h4>
        <div>
          KYC:
          {data.owner.kyc.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <div>
                <span>{index + 1}) </span>
                {item.id}
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.removeFirstItem}>Remove first item</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This did the trick. Thank you :)

Comment: @malikbagwala you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_.remove` or `_.filter`.

Please refer this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21281286/how-can-i-remove-an-element-from-a-list-with-lodash)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Array prototype method itself,
if you want to remove from the front

```
Array.prototype.shift.apply(data.owner.kyc,null)
```